# Error in programming STM32F4 Discovery with IAR?

Tags: interrupts, error, iar, stm32f4-discovery

I program STM32F4 using External Interrupt, and there is an error below:

[image]

Error[Li005]: no definition for "SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig" [referenced from C:\Users\AnhDoan\Desktop\STM32\IAR[GPIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9fJl.png) LED_Blink_Freq_Button\Debug\Obj\main.o]

Error while running Linker.

Code:

```
>     /* Traffic Light: LED13 for 10s, then LED14 for 5s, then LED15 for 10s Press the button: switch to the next LED immediately (order:
> LED13->14, LED14->LED14, LED15->LED13) Avoid pressing too fast
> */
> 
> #include "stm32f4xx.h"
> 
> 
> GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStructure; TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef 
> TIM_BaseStruct; EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure; NVIC_InitTypeDef
> NVIC_InitStructure;
> 
> void GPIO_Configuration(void); void TIM_Configuration(void); void
> EXTI_Configuration(void);
> 
> int main(void) {   GPIO_Configuration();   EXTI_Configuration();  
> TIM_Configuration();   while(1)   {   } }
> 
> 
> void GPIO_Configuration(void) {  
> RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13|GPIO_Pin_14|GPIO_Pin_15;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;   GPIO_Init(GPIOD,
> &GPIO_InitStructure); }
> 
> void EXTI_Configuration() {  
> RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);  
> RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);
>      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;  
> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;  
> GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&GPIO_InitStructure);
>      SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOA, EXTI_PinSource0);
>      EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line0;   EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;  
> EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;  
> EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising;  
> EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);
>      //Add Interrupt (IRQ) to NVIC   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI0_IRQn;  
> NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;  
> NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;  
> NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;  
> NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure); }
> 
> void TIM_Configuration(void) {  
> RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2,ENABLE);
>      TIM_BaseStruct.TIM_Prescaler = 21000-1;               //0.5s   TIM_BaseStruct.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;  
> TIM_BaseStruct.TIM_Period = 2000-1;   TIM_BaseStruct.TIM_ClockDivision
> = 0;   TIM_BaseStruct.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
>      TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2,&TIM_BaseStruct);
>      TIM_Cmd(TIM2,ENABLE);
>      NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x01;  
> NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;  
> NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;  
> NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure); }
> 
> 
> 
> #ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line) {    /* User can add his own implementation to report the file
> name and line number,
>      ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
> 
>   /* Infinite loop */   while (1)   {   } }
> #endif
```

Can you please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it (in detail) please. I checked but cannot find any error in the code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's a link error saying the symbol `SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig` doesn't exist. What does `EXTI_Configuration` contain?

Comment: If you post your code here, rather than a screenshot of some of it you'll get more help.

Comment: @Colin__s I have already added the code. Can you give me some more details? There is a definition of SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig in .h file, so why there is this error?

Comment: Do you have USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER defined in your project so the Standard Peripherals Library .h files are included (end of stm32f4xx.h inclusion of "stm32f4xx_conf.h")? Have you included the SPL in your project (or at least stm32f4xx_syscfg.c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is looking for the function SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig() but can't find it, probably because the source file is missing from your workspace.  The missing file is probably named something like stm32f4xx_syscfg.c

BTW, the "definition of SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig in .h file" is a declaration (prototype), not a definition.

Comment: stm32f4xx_syscfg.c may be found in the src directory of the Standard Peripherals Library, and yes SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig() is defined in that file.